# how to get the value of a variable used in a function inside GET request?

Tags: jquery, get, youtube-api

Hi I am using YouTube API to get video stats and I am making a GET request to API and am able to get response as well. Further I need to return variable value that is assigned in each loop. Below is the code and please tell me how can get the variable value outside GET request.

```
function getVideoCount(videoId) {
    var count = null;                
       $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
            part: 'statistics',
            id : videoId,
            key : 'AIzaSyB8BFP0N1eRGGhSh4xYYyz43QTBSHhOdy4'},                
            function(data){
                //console.log(data.items["statistics"]);
                $.each(data.items, function(i , item){
                    count =  item.statistics.viewCount;                     
                })
            //console.log(count);
            }
            //console.log(count)                    
    );
    console.log(count);
    return count;
}
```

Here, I need  value of `count` to be returned. It is now returning the value which I have assigned in the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get method is async, you can't just get it this way because your return occurs BEFORE your GET request end. 
A way to do is to have a callback on your getVideoCount function, and call it once your GET request end.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this functionality by use of Javascript closure. 
I found a similar example for this on: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp you can have look to understand.

I have written some example here you can have look:

```js
var count=(function(){
    
      var counter=0;
    
      return function (){
          
        counter+=1;
        return counter;
      }
    })();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count();
}
```

```html
<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>
```

Any update on counter goes inside inner function block.In your case you can call the get request inside that block ,update the counter and return its value on success callback.

Let me know if it helps.